# What is Alt+[num] doing on my HP laptop?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, shortcuts, hp-pavilion

Windows 10, HP Pavilion 15

I have a HP Pavilion 15 laptop, and a weird key combination I've never seen works on my laptop. Alt+[num] seems to switch Windows onto different 'sessions' or almost users.

- If I press Alt+1 nothing happens.
- If I press Alt+2, all the programs I have open close. If audio is playing, it continues playing. These programs aren't visible in Alt+Tab, Win+Tab or when swiping up with 3 fingers. I can open new windows in programs that can have multiple instances, but in those that cannot e.g. Spotify, opening it will bring up the initial instance.
- If I press Alt+1, I switch back to my 'original' screen.

I have no idea of the purpose of this and I in fact didn't know it existed til I mis-typed Alt+F4 a few times with the effect of closing all applications, some of which opened right up where they left off.

What is this combination? Is there documentation on it?

Note: my laptop has Fn lock on with no Fn lock key, so if I hit F6 then it mutes, without pressing any Fn key in liaison.

Comment: Try this document  ...... https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04270447

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a workspace, better known as a Virtual Desktop. I'm not familiar with the keyboard shortcuts, but [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/688608/keyboard-shortcuts-for-using-virtual-desktops-on-windows-10/) lists a few:

- Windows+Tab: Open Task View.
- Windows+Ctrl+D: Create a new virtual desktop.
- Windows+Ctrl+Left or Right Arrow: Switch between virtual desktops.
- Windows+Ctrl+F4: Close the current virtual desktop.
- Esc: Close Task View.

As for their usage, the basic idea is to let you switch between work without needing to close your programs. For example, you could have all of your programming work on one workstation (a text editor, some documentation, etc) and all of your social media (Facebook, Microsoft Team, etc) on another. Once you're done with one for the moment, you can instantly switch to another without having to tediously re-open everything.